# How can I narrow a type such that a field is no longer optional

Tags: typescript

I have a type that has an optional field but I want to be able to return a similar type where that field isn't optional. eg

```js
type Foo = {
  x?: string
}
type Bar = {x: string}

const fn = (foo: Foo): Bar => {
  if (foo.x) {
    return foo
  }

  throw new Error
}
```

however, this doesn't type check because `foo` isn't narrowed to `Bar`. Can this be solved without a cast?

[typescript play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKAPA-ALigGdgAnASwDsBzdAX3VEigCEBDU5NbQkimhugDGcSiSgAzSlwAUEhIXhwAlIXackAPjSYo5CVDkIAdNmU6sWUhGABXUtPlxdgrMAAWpOAHcolCL4AoqRepPRAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the argument could be mutated somewhere else later it's a bad idea to narrow it in this case. Instead it's better to return a copy.

```js
type Foo = {
  x?: string
}
type Bar = {x: string}

const fn = (foo: Foo): Bar => {
  if (foo.x) {
    return {x: foo.x}
  }

  throw new Error
}
```